# converting validation from the free pdf asp.net mvc nerdinner (c#) to vb.net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, vb.net

how would you convert this code into vb.net since vb doesn't have the **yield** keyword

thanks

```
public IEnumerable<RuleViolation> GetRuleViolations() {
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Title))
        yield return new RuleViolation("Title required", "Title");
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Description))
        yield return new RuleViolation("Description required","Description");
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(HostedBy))
        yield return new RuleViolation("HostedBy required", "HostedBy");
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Address))
        yield return new RuleViolation("Address required", "Address");
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Country))
        yield return new RuleViolation("Country required", "Country");
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(ContactPhone))
        yield return new RuleViolation("Phone# required", "ContactPhone");
    if (!PhoneValidator.IsValidNumber(ContactPhone, Country))
        yield return new RuleViolation("Phone# does not match country", "ContactPhone");
    yield break;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a List<RuleViolation> and instead of doing "yield return" just add those rules to the list. Then just simply return the list.

Comment: this works but the caveat is that it's not deferred execution--i.e., the CPU will have to complete the list first before returning as opposed to computing for each item in the list as requested.  that said, there is no direct equivalent of "yield return" in VB.NET so this is the quickest option.